# how to install app in sharepoint 2013 Publishing site?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-application, sharepoint-addin

I am trying to create one App for sharepoint 2013 publishing site. I can not see Apps catalog from where I can upload an app to the publishing site. On the other hand, if I see in developer site, I have that option available.

**Is there any way we can get the "apps in testing" feature enabled in publishing site as well??? 
Or what is the alternate to upload the app to publishing site?****

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

download the mandatory patch from Microsoft and install.
[patch for sharepoint 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=36989)